# Sorting Model A by Model B returning duplicates

Tags: django

I have Model called Games that has many posts connected by Model Posts. When I sort Games by Model Posts date posted it returns duplicates from Model Games. I'm wondering how I can display Games by most recent post date without returning duplicates.

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from library.models import Game
from .models import Post
from django.views.generic import (
ListView,
DetailView
)

# Create your views here.
def home(request):

    context = {
        'recent': Game.objects.all().order_by('-post__date_published')[:5],
        'posts': Post.objects.all(),
}
    return render(request, 'main/home.html', context)

class TitlePostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'main/title_posts.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 5


    def get_queryset(self):
        title = get_object_or_404(Game, title=self.kwargs.get('title'))
        return Post.objects.filter(game=title).order_by('-date_published')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TitlePostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['game'] = get_object_or_404(Game, title=self.kwargs.get('title'))
        return context

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
     model = Post
```

Models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    article_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="Article Title Place Holder")
    content = HTMLField(default="Article Content Pace Holder")
    date_published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    game = models.ForeignKey('library.Game', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article_image = models.ImageField(default='/media/default.png')

class Game(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    cover = models.ImageField()
    cover_display = models.ImageField(default='default.png')
    developer = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for here is `distinct()`.

`Game.objects.all().order_by('-post_set__date_published').distinct()[:5]`

I also don't see where you are connecting `Post` and `Game`, so I am assuming that you are doing that in some other code that you haven't posted and that your current `order_by` is working.

Comment: I edited my post. I just realized I wasn't even sorting by posts. I changed it but I'm still getting duplicates even after I inserted distinct(). I understand its because its duplicating for each post the game has. I'm just not sure how to make it sort by only the most recent post.

Comment: Are you trying to get the most recent post for each game, or are you trying to get the game with the most recent post?  There is a huge difference in how to go about achieving those two things.

Comment: The later is what I'm trying to get.

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect the new information.  So you should be sorting by `-post__date_published` to get the game with the most recent post.  As for the duplicates, could you please share the manner in which you are connecting `Post` and `Game`?

Comment: I uploaded my entire views.py

Comment: the bigger problem is your models.  The way it is now, I see no actual connection between `Post` and `Game`.  Andddd as I say that, I found it. Your `game` foreign key in `Post` has no `related_name` argument, so to get the posts given a game you need to say `post_set`.

Comment: Also, what are you currently getting returned to you?

Comment: With the way it is set up in the post above, django is basically pulling the 5 most recent posts and then displaying the game with those recent posts. So for example, the page returns: [Game A], [Game B], [Game C], [Game C], [Game D]. Which makes sense because Game C has 2 of the 5 most recent posts but I just want it to find the most recent post for each game and then sort those recent posts by the date. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Do you want games or posts?  Right now you are trying to get `games`

Comment: Try switching the order: `Game.objects.all().distinct().order_by('-post_set__date_published')`

Comment: I get this error: Cannot resolve keyword 'post_set' into field.

I'm not sure how I set post_set